# Google maps key error

Tags: google-maps, api-key

Last month I'm working on web site witch use Google Maps and all is working fine but, last week I'm getting error that my key is invalid for this version of Google maps? I get the same error if I run my site on localhost.

Why isn't this error is showing up now, but all month Was working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Domain Changed?
You Can Give another key [Here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html)

Comment: No my domain doesnt change. And i tried to generate a new key and i getting same error. Is possible that the error came becouse i generate key for the domain.com but my site is in domain.com/site.

Comment: for information for the other people! the google maps api v3 does not need any api key! so remove the key from definition url!(<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=sl"/>) thanks for help anyway!